# User input Error Python Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am trying to get the user input as either `'X'` or `'O'`. I keep getting an `EOF when reading a line`. I pasted my code below.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

def display_board(board):
    print(board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('--|---|--')
    print(board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('--|---|--')
    print(board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])

test_board = [' '] * 10
display_board(test_board)


def player_input():
    marker = ''


    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = raw_input('Player 1: Do you want to be X or O? ').upper()


    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X', 'O')
    else:
        return ('O', 'X')

player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input()
```

Comment: What is the full traceback of the error? What line does it happen on? Copying and pasting your code seems to work for me as expected.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out! Thanks for the help though

Comment: Great! I think the appropriate thing to do now is to answer your own question below, so anyone who comes along this post in the future with a similar problem knows how to solve it.